# Why Add-Migration suddenly generates a non empty code migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using EF6 Code based

My actual entities have not been changed, but a new DBSet was added to allow to query for a navigation property directly.

If I run **Add-Migration**, it generates a non empty migration with just a weird column rename for a foreign key.

```
public override void Up()
{
    RenameColumn(table: "dbo.ConfigurationPropertyBases", name: "ConfigurationClass_Id", newName: "ConfigurationClass_Id1");
    RenameIndex(table: "dbo.ConfigurationPropertyBases", name: "IX_ConfigurationClass_Id", newName: "IX_ConfigurationClass_Id1");
}
```

Why does it generate a migration like that?

Change in DbContext:

```
public class ConfigurationContext : DbContext
{
   //(...)

    public DbSet<ConfigurationPackage> Packages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ConfigurationPropertyBase> ConfigurationPropertyBases { get; set; }

    // THIS WAS ADDED
    public DbSet<ConfigurationClass> ConfigurationClass { get; set; }
}
```

The db model: (I only show relevant navigation properties).

```
public class ConfigurationPackage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //(...)
    public List<ConfigurationClass> Configurations { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigurationClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<ConfigurationPropertyBase> ConfigurationProperties { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ConfigurationPropertyBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //(no navigation propeties here)
}
```

I have a number of classes that inherit from ConfigurationPropertyBase, but all of them only contain simple properties like int or string (no navigation properties), except one which is:

```
public class ConfigurationPropertyComplex : ConfigurationPropertyBase
{
    public ConfigurationClass ConfigurationClass { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for ConfigurationPropertyBase also please. Also given the name includes the word Base I would ask if there are derived classes of this in your model  that have changed.

Comment: I actually found a change. I edited the question. It was not in the model classes, but in the DbContext. The question remains though. Why does it generate a migration like that?

Comment: EF generates the columns needed to store the relationship in a database, then manages them silently inside the DbContext while you work with your POCOs. Because you need to have some way to relate the two entities, EF will use the PK of the parent to define implicit foreign keys on the child entity. I'll update my answer to match.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework conventions will create a column to hold relationship information that is not explicitly defined in your model.
In the msdn [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/jj679962.aspx) it states:

> In addition to navigation properties, we recommend that you include foreign key properties on the types that represent dependent objects. Any property with the same data type as the principal primary key property and with a name that follows one of the following formats represents a foreign key for the relationship

With this in mind, you may not have changed your model in your mind but possibly in another class you have changed a navigation property with an implicit foreign key. Also depending on if you have derived classes of `ConfigurationPropertyBase` then changes in these will affect the model.

In any case follow the recommendation to explicitly define your foreign key properties and life becomes so much easier.
Also please update your question to include the `ConfigurationPropertyBase` class and one or two of its derivatives.

**EDIT** in response to updated question

As you found the change was in the context itself. When you added the `ConfigurationClass` to the context it had to rearrange its implicit foreign keys.

Again to quote the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564):

> When foreign key columns are not included in the model, the association information is managed as an independent object. Relationships are tracked through object references instead of foreign key properties. This type of association is called an independent association. The most common way to modify an independent association is to modify the navigation properties that are generated for each entity that participates in the association.

Take the advice and manage the foreign key properties explicitly so that EF doesn't decide on changes which don't seem to make sense.
For example:

```
public class ConfigurationPackage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //(...)
    [InverseProperty("ConfigurationPackage")]
    public List<ConfigurationClass> Configurations { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigurationClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ConfigurationPackage")]
    public int ConfigurationPackageId { get; set; }
    public ConfigurationPackage ConfigurationPackage { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ConfigurationClass")]
    public List<ConfigurationPropertyBase> ConfigurationProperties { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ConfigurationPropertyBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //(no navigation propeties here)
    [ForeignKey("ConfigurationClass")]
    public int ConfigurationClassId { get; set; }
    public ConfigurationClass ConfigurationClass { get; set; }
}
```

Yes it is a whole lot more work and more to learn but then EF will do exactly as you say. Again more [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#relationships) about data annotations should see you right.